# Нужна ли запятая и кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

Но (,) будучи уверенным в будущей роли мотора и видя его решение каноническим, я дал ему вызывающее громкое название ДАР (двигатель аксиальный реверсивный)...

Comment: @Alenka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Запятая перед "будучи" нужна. См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121 :

> **§ 68.** Обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастными оборотами, выделяются
> запятыми, независимо от места
> расположения по отношению к
> глаголу-сказуемому...
>
> Деепричастный оборот, находящийся
> после союза или союзного слова,
> отделяется от него запятой (**союзы не
> включаются в деепричастный
> оборот**)...

**P.S.**

Обратил только что внимание на слово "вызывающее". Я бы прилагательное заменил наречием:

*...**вызывающе** громкое*...

Если же оставить прилагательное, то тогда после него нужно будет поставить запятую:

*...я дал ему вызывающее, громкое название...*

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Внимание обращают на себя "роль мотора" - без уточнения в чём, а также "решение каноническое" - странные словосочетания на взгляд не знатока моторов. И ещё. Аббревиатура определила название мотора, поэтому правильнее было бы так: я остановился на логичном, хотя и вызывающе громком имени ДАР (...).